# category navigation in Magento

Tags: magento

I've setup a custom menu in my magento (v 1.6) as a block. How can I make it dynamic calling items based on their category that was assigned.

My menu looks something like this.

Vegetables

- tomatoes
- cucumbers
- squash

Meat

- Pork
- Chicken
- Beef

I need to list all the items under each category ('Meat', 'Vegetable'). I'm not sure how to implement this properly, as the 'blocks' doesn't support php. please advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can check out the code in the following link and edit it according to your needs

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/getting_and_using_categories_and_subcategories